# How to solve this recurrence using back substitution: $T(n)=T(n^{1/2})+n$ where T(2)=1

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve this recurrence using back substitution.

> $$T(n)=T(n^{1/2})+n$$
>   where T(2)=1

I solved it and got the kth term as follows:

> $$T(n)=T(n^{1/2^k})+(n)^{1/2}+(n)^{1/2^2}+(n)^{1/2^3}+....(n)1/{2^{{k-1}}}+n$$

But i don't have any idea how to deal with this series.Please give me some idea to solve this series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your sequence is defined only for $n=2^{2^k}$, $k\ge 0$, it seems useful to rewrite it as

$$S(k):=T(2^{2^k}),\quad k\ge 0.$$
Then you are able to write it as
$$S(k+1) = S(k) + 2^{2^{k+1}}, \quad S(0) = 1.$$
It would give $$S(k) = -1+\sum_{s=0}^k 2^{2^s}.$$

Comment: Hence $S(k)\sim2^{2^k}$.

Comment: Pls explain a little bit more!

Comment: what abt $$(n)^{1/2}+(n)^{1/2^2}+(n)^{1/2^3}+....(n)^{1/2^{{k−1}}}+n$$

Comment: @Did indeed it is. Though I don't really see a closed form for $S(k)$ other than the direct sum.

Comment: @Coffee_lover Your expression is the same as mine up to a change $2^{2^k}\to n$. Please specify where you need more clarifications, I don't see any hard points there.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I agree with you about the probable absence of closed form formula.